# Examples of API key usage and checking?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, go

In the Google Developers Console, one can read an API key for public access to their own API. When creating this API key you can specify what referrers are to be used with what keys.

I've looked around, and haven't found examples of how to pass this API key from a web client call in JavaScript nor have I been able to find how the API can check for the existence of this key and that it matches the referrer expectations as set in the Developer Console.

Does anyone have examples on this?

Answer (score 0):

To talk to googles APIs you need an OAuth2 token. The scenario you're asking about (and more) is detailed here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Edit: the specific client side use case is documented here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: I think that's inaccurate: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys also, I'm talking about my own API hosted on App Engine... Not Google's APIs per se.

Comment: Hmmm... This may be the closest to what I need minus the OAuth authorization: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/

Comment: Did you see the example Google has https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#webapp ? If i'm misunderstanding your question, can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, however that calls Google's API, and does explain anything about how the API key is sent over the wire... Whether it's in the header or as a param... And then no example on the API side on how to verify that the key matches what was specified in the developer console in the referrer field.

Comment: So let me understand this. You have an app on GAE which exposes a RESTful API and you want to allow authenticated javascript clients the ability to call this API?

Comment: I only want my JavaScript app from my domain to use the API exposed via GAE endpoints. Basically I have an API key set up already, but what does GAE offer in terms of validating that the usage of said key matches the restrictions I put on it? Clearly I need to check the existence of the key and those restrictions before my API does anything...

Comment: From my perspective, GAE should expose a validate_api_key method. But if it doesn't I need to write that method, checking for the presence of the key and ensuring that the referrer or remote ip is my website, rejecting all other requests.

Comment: OK so it looks like it passed as query parameter key=<token>. I think this is what you want, it talks about securing it to just your site etc https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys If it's not what you want then i'm sorry, i can't help :(

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but there's no example of usage of the key from the JS client or how to check the key in the endpoint. I guess I'm just going to have to play with this until I figure it out. Thanks for the suggestions though.